# Как сравнить два вектора массивов?

Tags: массивы, vector, сравнение, c++

Имеется `vector<int**>`, в нем находятся несколько сотен тысяч массивов. Массивы `int*` имеют одинаковый размер (пример: `{2,6,8,9,3,5,1,4,7}`).

Необходимо подсчитать количество одинаковых массивов.

На ум приходит, что то такое:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < vectorSize; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < vectorSize; k++)
            if (vector[i][k] == vector[j][k])
                    n++;
```

Но так к массиву внутри вектора нельзя обращаться и считать будет долго.

Comment: Я бы сделал вектор хэш-кодов массивов (это 2 вложенных цикла)

(а реально, вектор таких структур 

     struct a_signature {
        uint64_t hash;
        int  *array;
     };

),

отсортировал его по hash и уже среди одинаковых hash проводил поэлементное сравнение.

Кстати, непосредственно сравнение  2-х массивов можно делать функцией `memcmp()` (см. man 3 memcmp)

Comment: А почему странный гибрид из C и C++? Почему внешний у вас `vector`, а внутренний `int*`?

Comment: Получаю массивы int* из функции, которую не я писал и редактировать нет возможности =(

Comment: avp, со структурами не работал. Как будет выглядеть объявление вектора? И как сортировать по hash?

Comment: @PastoriXx: структура практически ничем не отличается от класса (просто обычно в неё не кладут логику, а пользуются внешними функциями). Для сортировки можно воспользоваться вариантом [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) с кастомной функцией сравнения (примените лямбду, если компилятор позволяет; примеры по ссылке).

Comment: непонятно: нужно сравнить два вектора vector<int*> или подсчитать количество одинаковых массивов в одном векторе?